# MySQL Workbench much faster than Python for the same query

Tags: python, mysql

The following query in MySQL Workbench takes 0.156 second to complete:

```
SELECT 
    date, time, minute_price_id 
FROM 
    minute_prices 
WHERE 
    contract_id = 673 AND 
    TIMESTAMP(date, time) >= '2013-05-15 13:15:00' AND 
    TIMESTAMP(date, time) <= '2015-02-23 13:15:00'
LIMIT 1000000;
```

While the same query in Python using mysql.connector takes over 3.3 seconds:

```
import mysql.connector
con = mysql.connector.connect(...)
cur = con.cursor()

sql = \
    """
    SELECT 
        date, time, minute_price_id 
    FROM 
        minute_prices 
    WHERE 
        contract_id = 673 AND 
        TIMESTAMP(date, time) >= '2013-05-15 13:15:00' AND 
        TIMESTAMP(date, time) <= '2015-02-23 13:15:00'
    """
cur.execute(sql)
cur.fetchall()
```

I expected MySQL Workbench to be faster than Python because data needs to be transferred, but 20x faster? Any clue? Thank you.

Comment: What about the `LIMIT 1000000`?

Comment: Only 55000 rows are returned. I just added it to the Workbench to make sure I was comparing apples to apples.

Comment: Lower the limit to e.g. 5000 - if the difference becomes less, you can be pretty sure that it's the transfer speed.

Comment: Yep, with a limit of 5000 Python is 10x faster (because it's 10x smaller as well), but the ratio with MySQL remains the same (20x slower).

Comment: import MySQLdb.cursors

self.db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", db="ibeat", cursorclass = MySQLdb.cursors.SSCursor)

Try this

Comment: Thanks Murali. The SSCursor is indeed faster - it has reduced the time by 3.

Comment: @user1242808 python is known for its slow speed so idk if it is so surprising...

Answer (score 1):

There are a few reasons I can think of to explain this:

1. Python has to start, whereas you already have workbench running.
2. Python has to load your program, whereas workbench doesn't.
3. Python has to open a connection to the database whereas workbench (I assume) already has one.

In order to sort this out, try using the timeit python module (or do manual timing) and only include the execute/fetchall commands.