# SQL Alchemy Painfully Slow when Querying Database Using an MYSQL Query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm running a fairly straightforward MYSQL query in python using SQL Alchemy on a relatively small MySQL 
database.

If I run the query on MySQL Workbench the query is blazing fast.

Here is the query code:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:*****@12.345.67.890:3306/mydb')


script = '''
     SELECT t.Name, t.Description, t.abbreviation, p.Date, p.numericaldata1,p.numericaldata2
     FROM basicinfo t
     JOIN (detailedinfo p)
     ON (p.Name = t.Name)

     '''
with engine.connect() as con:

    ResultSet = con.execute(script)
    df = pd.DataFrame(ResultSet)
    df.columns = ResultSet.keys()
```

The script above pulls from two tables.  One is about 500 rows by 5 columns.  The other is about 1.5 M rows by 10 columns.

This has something to do with SQL Alchemy since MySQL workbench works quickly.

Comment: Consider trying different connection packages. `pymysql` is pure python, which cause some overhead when fetching large numbers of records.  Also, make sure you aren't including Pandas overhead in your timings.

Comment: Is the workbench running locally and accesses the DB remotely? Does it fetch full results or possibly a limited sample set? Have you benchmarked just the query without wrapping with pandas dataframe? Passing the result set like that to pandas will mean it is iterated over, i.e. fetchone, fetchone, fetchone, etc.
 What are the actual times?

Comment: It'd also be interesting to know what version of MySQL you're running. Also, SQLA might not be the (only) culprit here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28744671/mysql-workbench-much-faster-than-python-for-the-same-query

Comment: Looking at https://superuser.com/questions/240291/how-to-remove-1000-row-limit-in-mysql-workbench-queries it does seem like Workbench by default limits results to a 1000, which of course would be a lot faster to fetch than potentially millions. Have you disabled that limit, or does it even apply to your case?

Comment: Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE basicinfo; B) SHOW CREATE TABLE detailinfo; and C) EXPLAIN SELECT (your query); for analysis.

Comment: All queries run both locally and remotely.  Workbench has a default of 1000 but can be adjusted.  Was run for the whole data set.  Workbench performs fast and SQL Alchemy slowly both locally and remotely.  Running MySQL version 8.0.19.  Pandas conversion overhead is minimal

Comment: Please post from SQL ALCHEMY MySQL instance, TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE basicinfo; B) SHOW CREATE TABLE detailinfo; and C) your slow query and D) EXPLAIN SELECT (your slow query); for analysis.